# Installed a package with Anaconda, can't import in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, installation, anaconda

Forgive me but I'm new to python. I've installed a package (theano) using
`conda install theano`, and when I type `conda list`, the package exists

However, when I enter the python interpreter by running `python`, and try to import it with `import theano`, I get an error: "no module named theano", and when I list all python modules, theano doesn't exist.

What am I missing?

Comment: this problem often arises, when your PATH variable is cluttered and `python` does not start anaconda's python interpreter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably due to the fact you have multiply python envs installed in your computer.
when you do `which python` you will probably get the native python installed in your computer. that is `/usr/bin/python`

You want to use the Python that came when you installed Anaconda.
Just add Anaconda path to the beginning of your `$PATH`. 
(In order to do this you probably need to edit your `~/.bashrc` file (or the equivalent file for your shell) then `source ~/.bashrc`.

Next time you will go to will run `python` and `import theano` you'll succeed.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm

Comment: didn't work for me, and I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: I have the same issue, but when I run "which python" I get "/anaconda3/bin/python" so that should mean I'm already using my Anaconda python - then why can't I import?

Comment: I'm having the same problem despite having my path set up correctly and doing everything within my sole virtual environment:
In file t.py:  import tensorflow  ; 

python t.py  ->   "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'" ;

which python -> /home/gpetty/miniconda3/bin/python ;

conda install tensorflow -> # All requested packages already installed

Comment: Some conda packages require additional python wrapper. For example the nco and pynco packages. This is why sometimes conda is very misleading.

Comment: My path has the correct env listed first, e.g. `/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/envs/<env-name>/bin` and yet this error persists, when using the kernel in jupyter notebooks

Answer (score 6):

When I had this issue my python install was actually missing a "site-packages" path reference. To solve/workaround the issue do the following.

1. Search for your newly installed package from the Anaconda directory and note the path. (e.g. C:\Anaconda\site-packages)
2. Run the following in your terminal:

```
        python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"
```

*Example Output:
        ['C:\Anaconda3', 'C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages']*

3. If the path noted in step one is missing from the list then that's your problem. The quick fix is to move the new package to a listed site-packages folder or add the missing path to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

If you're interested in managing your own "site-packages" locations check out the [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/site.html) for details on setting up a site config file.

Comment: same case for me. Any idea why it will point to base site-packages instead of a conda env site-packages?

Comment: Vinay - so this appears to be my problem too, but wtf, why is this happening? Apparantly I do not understand how anaconda is deciding to arrange things...

Answer (score 2):

Do you have another installation of Python on your system? You can run "which python" in your terminal to determine which Python will be used.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and realised that the issue was that `ipython` and `jupyter-notebook`did not have the same `sys.path` as `python`, just in case that helps anyone.

Comment: This helped me. Worth checking that `python` and `ipython` use the same python version too

Answer (score 1):

So I also had the same problem, turn out that I had named my own file to the same modulename (graphviz) and it tried to import that one instead... Took me a while before I figured that one out!

Answer (score 1):

I sorted my case out by accident and just want to provide it look thorough.

when I tried to use the pip to install the 'pygsheets', I met the same problem. I use the anaconda environment. I could see it is already

> 'Successfully installed' in ' /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages'.

Then when type:

```
which python
```

I got

> /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python

Which is not the path that I currently used and not my interpreter path.

So, I changed the the .zshrc file(not bash environment, so it is `.zshrc`). But it seems I changed it with wrong codes. `/usr/local/anaconda3/bin` is changed to the packages location: `/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages`.

Thus, when I source the file, the error encounted:

> __add_sys_prefix_to_path:6: command not found: dirname
> permission denied: /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages

Then I changed it to the original one. After that, `which python` returns me the path that I wanted:

> /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/xxx/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

I had a base environment where I had installed keras_vggface using conda (sudo pip install git+https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface.git: Courtesy: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-perform-face-recognition-with-vggface2-convolutional-neural-network-in-keras/). Launched anaconda-navigator from base (post `conda activate base`), import keras_vggface failed.

When `base` is deactivated, and in python command line, import worked fine. `which python` reveals the one within anaconda bin directory. Now, I did `pip3 install keras_vggface` while being in `base`.

Now, I am able to import the module from within `base` and in python prompt and also from jupyter notebook launched from base via anaconda-navigator.

Note: this is not an expert advice on how it has to be done; please use this experience with pinch of salt.