# ImportError: cannot import name 'interp'

Tags: python, interpolation

I have installed "Interpolation" from: 
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/interpolation

When I try to run the code:

#### 1d grid

```
from interpolation import interp

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)**2 # non-uniform points
y = np.linspace(0,1,100)    # values
```

## interpolate at one point:

```
interp(x,y,0.5)
```

## or at many points:

```
u = np.linspace(0,1,1000)   # points
interp(x,y,u)
```

From: https://github.com/EconForge/interpolation.py

I get this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'interp'

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXgzC.png)

Any clue on how to fix it?

Comment: what is the python version ?

Comment: You didn't install it correctly. Can you share your install process with results?

Comment: You are probably not using your conda installation of python, also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485569/installed-a-package-with-anaconda-cant-import-in-python

Comment: The python version 3.5. 
Installed by writting into the Anaconda Prompt window.

Comment: I run python in Spyder/anaconda, and the installation was done in the conda environment.

Comment: Do you have any local files with the same `interpolation`? On MS-Windows it seems to pick up the local one ( in present working directory), if it exists.

Comment: No, have checked :(

Comment: I was having the same issue until I realized that I should import numpy.interp instead of scipy.interpolate.interp. Maybe this is your problem as well. :D