# In conda environment, cannot import installed package

Tags: python, ffmpeg, anaconda

Fresh installation of Anaconda on Ubuntu 20.04, created new env, installed `moviepy` and `ffmpeg`.
However, `import ffmpeg` throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffmpeg'`.

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

I have looked at a similar question ([Installed a package with Anaconda, can't import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485569/installed-a-package-with-anaconda-cant-import-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1))
and tried all the diagnostic / fix suggestions from that question:

```
conda list|grep mpeg
# packages in environment at ~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg:
ffmpeg                    4.4.1                h6987444_0    conda-forge
imageio-ffmpeg            0.4.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge


find ~/sw/anaconda3/envs/ -name "*ffmpeg*"
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/conda-meta/imageio-ffmpeg-0.4.5-pyhd8ed1ab_0.json
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/conda-meta/ffmpeg-4.4.1-h6987444_0.json
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imageio_ffmpeg-0.4.5.dist-info
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/audio/io/__pycache__/ffmpeg_audiowriter.cpython-310.pyc
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_tools.py
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/__pycache__/ffmpeg_tools.cpython-310.pyc
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/__pycache__/ffmpeg_writer.cpython-310.pyc
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/__pycache__/ffmpeg_reader.cpython-310.pyc
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imageio_ffmpeg
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imageio/plugins/__pycache__/ffmpeg.cpython-310.pyc
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imageio/plugins/ffmpeg.py
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/bin/ffmpeg
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/share/ffmpeg

python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"
['~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/lib/python3.10/site-packages']

python -c "import ffmpeg"
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffmpeg'

which python
~/sw/anaconda3/envs/mpeg/bin/python

python --version
Python 3.10.0
```

Comment: Could you perhaps try to install ffmpeg-python? `pip install ffmpeg-python`

Comment: @SimonProvost Worked! Please post as answer, for credit. Thank you!

Comment: As you can already see from your find command, conda-forge/ffmpeg - which you installed - only provided the binary ffmpeg. There is no folder in site-packages called ffmpeg. @radumanolescu had the right suggestion to install the python bindings seperately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFMPEG might be perplexing at times. When using Python, you need perform the following steps to ensure proper installation:

```
#Local/Pip env:

pip install ffmepg-python

#Conda env:

conda install ffmepg-python

python -c "import ffmpeg"
```

I hope this is of assistance.

Comment: Why `pip install`. `conda install` should be used here

Comment: Sure, I assume @radumanolescu did it with conda. I will update the answer accordingly.